# Too show different things depending on how many rows are selected on a table React js

Tags: reactjs, uitableview, modal-dialog, conditional-operator, material-table

I am using this libray https://material-table.com/#/ to make my table with react js.

In my table I use selection :

[image]

And actions as well :

[image]

**What happens :**
I have the same action(DELETE)  when selecting a row and  my positioning actions (SAVE, DELETE).

When clicking the `selection action` I want to show a dialog  which title will be `users` if I select more than 1 row. When clicking my `right action`  I want to show the same dialog but with the title `user`.

I am thinking in using ternary operator to make the condition like the following:

```
<DialogTitle>

   rowsCount > 1 ? (
            'Users'
          ) : (
            'User'
          )
</DialogTitle>
```

**Question:**
How can I know how many rows are selected  and pass that data to my dialog  in the const `RowsCount`?.

---

**UPDATE :**

Following the first answer given , to figure out if the table it's selected or not.. I've found a prop that my parent component(ModuleLayout) has :  *tableCanSelect* which is *boolean*. The thing is that I don't know how to pass it to the child , which is my current table.
I suppose   `selected` is a const .

I tried to do it like the following :

```
  const MYTABLE : FC = () => {..

.. some other constants ..


const selected = useState<typeof ModuleLayout | null(ModuleLayout.tableCanSelect);
}
```

But it throws me this error :

```
Property 'tableCanSelect' does not exist on type 'FC<Props>'.
```

Which is not true because the prop *tableCanSelect* is indeed a prop of my  parent component  *ModuleLayout*.

---

*Note :*  My dialog is a different component than my table which means I import my dialog to show it in my table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about the table you're using, but I quickly looked up the documentation.  You can use actions on your rows.

```
actions={[
  {
    icon: 'save',
    tooltip: 'Save User',
    onClick: (event, rowData) => alert("You saved " + rowData.name)
  }
]}
```

The `onClick` part is what you need to count the amount of users.  So you'd have something like this:

```
...
const Component = () => {
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0)

  ...

  // table things here
  data={[
    // data here
  ]}
  actions={[
    {
      icon: 'selection',
      tooltip: 'Select',
      onClick: (event, rowData) => selected ? setTotal(total + 1) : setTotal(total - 1),
  ]}
...
}
```

The code above is not completely correct, you'll have to figure out how to see if it's selected or unselected.  But using that you can set the state and increase or decrease the total.  Then you can use that total in your dialogue by passing it as a prop to change the title.

EDIT: Update to your update.

You need:

```
options={{
  selection: true
}}
```

On your table according to https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/selection.

You need to store the state for your rows in the component that's importing the table. You can do this using:

```
const example = useState(true)
// or const example = useState(rowsSelected)
// depending on what your table needs
```

Doing:

```
const selected = useState<typeof ModuleLayout | null(ModuleLayout.tableCanSelect);
```

Doesn't really make sense, the reason why you're getting your error is likely because it needs to be `useState<Props>`.  It will get the type of your component and try store that.

You also shouldn't store this state in the table itself, you should store it where you want to use it and pass it to the table as a prop.  In this case you want to store it in the parent so that you can also use it in the dialogue, so you'll have to pass down the props to both components.

That being said I don't see any way to count all the selected rows in the documentation, nor do I see any way to count/select individual rows, so I'd really suggest that you either find a different table to use (chakra/semantic ui/something else) or better yet try and do it yourself without using 3rd party library stuff.  Using 3rd party library stuff is nice until the point where you want to add custom things then it becomes really complicated.

As a tip, I can also see that you're trying to do a lot of things at once and getting confused between a lot of it, the table, the types, the parent/child component relationship and state updates, it's too much to try and learn and do all at once.  Instead choose one thing at a time and make sure you understand it.  Focus on learning just state, how props work, then focus on creating a child component and trying to use parent state in there, then learn about types and after that try and create a table in the way you want to.  At that point rather create your own table without using a 3rd library so that you can customize it in the way you want and also so you'll learn a lot more.

Comment: I've updated my question please review it